# Calculate the max length of a regex output string

Tags: php, regex

A user can define the format of an identifier in my system, and this is stored in the d/b as a regex string (for example, "`/^\d{6}$/`", or a more complicated example of "`/^[A-Z]{2}\d{8}$/`").

Can anyone suggest how I can calculate the maximum length of the string that the given regex can match (thanks @Ulver)?

Many thanks for reading!

Comment: What should be max length of `.*` ?

Comment: You want way to calculate maximum length of the string that the given regex can match?

Comment: Maybe you would like to have a look at [Generate strings based on regular expressions with Hoa\Regex](http://mnt.io/P/2014-09-30_Generate_strings_based_on_regular_expressions.html) and then check the length of the strings generated. [Link to the Hoa library](https://github.com/hoaproject/Regex/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes 5 things:

1. The expressions are simple, as per your examples.
2. You do not have `*` or `+` operators in your expression.
3. You do not have patterns of the type `foo{n, }`, where `n` is some positive, integer value.
4. Each expression starts with `^` and ends with `$`.
5. I am also assuming that each term is followed by the amount of times you expect to match it.

To calculate the amount of characters they match, you could go through the expression and look for 2 patterns:

1. `{n}`, which translates to match exactly `n` times. In this case, extract `n`.
2. `{n, m}`, which translates to match at least `n` times, and at most `m` times. In this case, extract `m`.

Once that you will have all the `n` and `m` values, you would simply add them together.

---

Some more details on the assumptions:

1. As expressions get more complicated, you will need to keep track of various characters. For instance, `^[A-Z]{2}$` means match 2 upper case letters. Thus, the length of what is matched will be 2. On the other hand, `foo{2}` means `fooo`. But `afooo` and `foooobar` will also be matched. Thus, you have no control over the lenght of the pattern. also `(abc){2}` means match `abc` twice, thus, in this case, you would need to multiply the value of `n` (the value in the braces) with the length of what ever lies within the brackets which precede it, if any. Of course, you could have nested values.
2. The `*` and `+` operator denote 0 or more, and 1 or more respectively. Thus, there is, theoretically, no limit on the length of whatever it is matched.
3. Similar to point 2, `{n,}` means match at least `n` times. Thus, there is no upper limit.
4. Similar to point 1, without the `^` and `$` anchor, an expression can match any string. The expression `foo` can match `afoo`, `foobar`, `foooooooooooooooooooooooo` and so on.
5. I took this assumption for reasons similar to point 1. You could enhance your application to look for `[]` pairs and count them as 1 character, but I think you could have other caveats.

Comment: tl;dr Parse the regex.

Comment: @nhahtdh: If you want a comprehensive solution, which the answer provided does not cover, yes. In which case, may God have mercy on your soul....